# Count the number of files in a directory containing two specific string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, find

I have few files in a directory containing below pattern:

```
Simulator tool completed simulation at 20:07:18 on 09/28/18.
The situation of the simulation: STATUS PASSED
```

Now I want to count the number of files which contains both of strings `completed simulation` & `STATUS PASSED` anywhere in the file.

This command is working to search for one string `STATUS PASSED` and count file numbers:

```
find /directory_path/*.txt -type f -exec grep -l "STATUS PASSED" {} + | wc -l
```

Sed is also giving 0 as a result:

```
find /directory_path/*.txt -type f -exec sed -e '/STATUS PASSED/!d' -e '/completed simulation/!d' {} + | wc -l
```

Any help/suggestion will be much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec \
awk '/completed simulation/{x=1} /STATUS PASSED/{y=1} END{if (x&&y) print FILENAME}' {} \; |
wc -l
```

I'm printing the matching file names in case that's useful in some other context but piping that to wc will fail if the file names contain newlines - if that's the case just print 1 or anything else from awk.

Since `find /directory_path/*.txt -type f` is the same as just `ls /directory_path/*.txt` if all of the ".txt"s are files, though, it sounds like all you actually need is (using GNU awk for `nextfile`):

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { x=y=0 }
    /completed simulation/ { x=1 }
    /STATUS PASSED/        { y=1 }
    x && y { cnt++; nextfile }
    END { print cnt+0 }
' /directory_path/*.txt
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { x=y=f=0 }
    /completed simulation/ { x=1 }
    /STATUS PASSED/        { y=1 }
    x && y && !f { cnt++; f=1 }
    END { print cnt+0 }
' /directory_path/*.txt
```

Those will work no matter what characters are in your file names.

Answer (score 0):

The command `find /directory_path/*.txt` just lists all txt files in `/directory_path/` not including subdirectories of `/directory_path`

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 |
while read -d $'\0' file; do
  grep -Fq 'completed simulation' "$file" &&
  grep -Fq 'STATUS PASSED' "$_" &&
  echo "$_"
done |
wc -l
```

If you ensure no special characters in the filenames

```
find . -name \*.txt |
while read file; do
  grep -Fq 'completed simulation' "$file" &&
  grep -Fq 'STATUS PASSED' "$file" &&
  echo "$file"
done |
wc -l
```

*I don't have AIX to test it, but it should be POSIX compliant.*

Comment: Thanks, @Feng! Its working in linux but giving error in AIX: `find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.`

Comment: `-print0` is GNU find only. You're correctly protecting against file names that contain newlines but you should add `IFS=` to the `while read` to protect against file names that start/end with spaces and add `-r` to protect against file names that contain escape characters too. See the accepted answer at [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for an explanation of the default syntax for a while read loop - `while IFS= read -r line; do`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and standard utils:

```
{ grep -Hm1 'completed simulation' /directory_path/*.txt;
  grep -Hm1 'STATUS PASSED'        /directory_path/*.txt ; } |
sort | uniq -d | wc -l
```

---

`grep -m1` stops when it finds the first match.  This saves time if it's a big file.  If the list of matches is large, `sort -t: -k1` would be better than `sort`.